# Não consigo enviar arquivos para o projeto no github

Tags: github

Estou tentando colocar uma página html no ar, mas nada acontece e aparece o erro no terminal do git:

> Everything up-to-date

Segue comandos que usei:

```
 cd Desktop/ 

 cd projeto-html/

 git init .

 git remote add origin https://github.com/GuigaPassos/GuigaPassos.github.io.git

 git pull origin master

 git add .

 git push origin master
```

Depois disso aparece:

> Everything up-to-date

Comment: Oque está tentando enviar?, 'git status' para ver as modificações, 'git add - All' para adicionar ao container e git commit -m "msg do commit"; para comitar, após isso acontece o push

Comment: @FelipeDuarte  Estou tentando enviar meu arquivo "index.html" e o "README" atualizado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de realizar o `push` você precisa realizar um `commit`, faça:

```
git commit -am 'Mensagem do commit'
```

A mensagem `Everything up-to-date` indica que seu repositório está atualizado

Comment: Não mudou nada, quero colocar meu site no ar através do github

Comment: Dá um `git remote`, qual a saída?

Comment: Eu dou f5 na página do GitHub e nada mudou

Comment: Os arquivos não foram enviados, faça assim: `git add *`; `git commit -am 'Mensagem'`; `git push origin master`

Comment: Consegui, funcionou, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Como foi o seu procedimento?

Você criou primeiro o repositório no GitHub e fez o clone?

Ou criou um diretório na sua máquina e agora quer enviar para o GitHub?

No GitHub, você marcou a opção de inicializar o diretório? ou não?

A forma mais fácil é:

> 1. Crie o repositório no GitHub, marque a opção para criar o README.
> 2. Faça um git clone URL para o seu computador.
> 3. Copie os arquivos que deseja enviar para o Git. (Eu acho importante
>      antes de commitar criar um .gitignore. Com esse arquivo você
>      configura o que não quer enviar para o servidor git. Como por
>      exemplos arquivos temporários nos sistemas. Com maven em Java, eu
>      não preciso guardar a pasta target por exemplo. Projetos feitos com
>      NetBeans ou outras IDEs eu posso escolher não salvar os arquivos de
>      configuração do projeto que são criados para a máquina do usuário.
>      Aqui nesse [link](https://github.com/github/gitignore) tem um monte de exemplo, para projetos em
>      diversas linguagens.
> 4. git commit -am "MENSAGEM DE COMMIT"
> 5. git push (pronto os arquivos serão transferidos para o Git ou
>      GitHub)